# Perpendicular Lines and all $x$-axis points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

Find the coordinates of all the points $P$ on the $x$-axis so that the line $A(1, 2)$ and $P$ is perpendicular to $B(8, 3)$ and $P$.

The answer is $(7, 0)$ and $(2, 0)$, which I understand are the x-intercepts of the two lines. How is this worked? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with the dot product (or the relationship between slopes of perpendicular lines)?

Answer (score 1):

Say the coordinates of $P$ are $(x,0)$.

$AP\perp BP$ means the dot product $(1-x,2)\cdot(8-x,3)=0$.

This simplifies to $(x-1)(x-8)+6=x^2-9x+14=0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. I see what I was doing wrong. I was going about the slopes by trying to find each line's equation and then solving for the x-int. I couldnt solve for the equation because I was using the point of intersection P(x,y)  and let's say, A.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you might know that the product of the slopes of two perpendicular lines is -1. The slope of the line between $(1,2)$ and $(x, 0)$ is $\frac{0-2}{x-1}$ and the slope of the line between $(8,3)$ and $(x,0)$ is $\frac{0-3}{x-8}$, so using the aforementioned perpendicularity property we have
$$
\frac{0-2}{x-1} \cdot \frac{0-3}{x-8} = -1 \implies (x-1)\cdot(x-8) = -6 \implies x^2 -9x +14 = 0
$$
the same equation that J.W. Tanner got through a slightly different method.

Comment: Thank you! Ive got to ways now to study this now